# Insert in procedure of mysql will not lock a table

Tags: mysql, insert, locking

I have a procedure of mysql:

```
START TRANSACTION;

insert into table1(id, name) values(1, 'a'); -- id is a primary key.
...
delete from table1 where id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

and a multithread call to this procedure will show error in jdbc
Duplicate entry '1' for key table1_UNIQUE_key'

why the other thread will not wait for this thread end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because If you check, you have declared the table as `INODB` engine, which allows a row level lock, if it had been `MYSAM` this problem would not occur